# Why does enumerating though a NSDictionary not return the input sequence?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I've noticed that the enumerated output of a NSDictionary is not returning the same sequence as the order in which the items were added.

```
NSMutableArray *arrKeys;
NSMutableArray *arrValues;
NSDictionary *items;

arrKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
arrValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

[arrKeys addObject:@"A"]; [arrValues addObject:@"First"];
[arrKeys addObject:@"B"]; [arrValues addObject:@"Second"];
[arrKeys addObject:@"C"]; [arrValues addObject:@"Third"];
[arrKeys addObject:@"D"]; [arrValues addObject:@"Fourth"];
[arrKeys addObject:@"E"]; [arrValues addObject:@"Last"];

items = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrValues forKeys:arrKeys];

for (NSString *aKey in items) {
    NSLog(@"%@=%@", aKey, [items valueForKey:aKey]);
}
```

Returns...

A=First
D=Fourth
B=Second
E=Last
C=Third

I appreciate that a Dictionary allows you to randomly access items by key, but is there some rationale for the arbitrary order they are returned while enumerating the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just that, an `NSDictionary` does not guarantee iteration order. This is consistent with the behavior you'd expect from a typical hash table -- optimized for quick lookup, but not for ordered iteration.

Why not iterate through `arrKeys` that you already have?

Comment: It was merely an observation that came about when we converted the dictionary to JSON. It's not critical for this situation, but there may be another occasion in the future where order is important.